# How to use sqlite3 with docker compose

Tags: node.js, docker, sqlite, docker-compose, sequelize.js

Between the following tutorials;

- [Dockerizing create-react-app](https://mherman.org/blog/2017/12/07/dockerizing-a-react-app/)
- [Developing microservices - Node, react & docker](https://mherman.org/blog/2017/05/11/developing-microservices-node-react-docker/#web-service---part-1)

I have been able to convert my nodejs app to dockerized micro-services which is up and running and connecting to services. However, my app uses Sqlite/Sequelize and this was working perfectly prior to dockerizing.

With the new setup, I get error;

```
/usr/src/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/connection-manager.js:31
throw new Error('Please install sqlite3 package manually');
Error: Please install sqlite3 package manually at new ConnectionManager 
(/usr/src/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/connection-manager.js:31:15)
```

My question is;

1. Is it possible to use Sqlite3 with Docker
2. If so, anyone able to share sample docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile combo that works for this please.

***My docker-compose.yml***

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  user-service:
    container_name: user-service
    build: ./services/user/
    volumes:
      - './services/user:/usr/src/app'
      - './services/user/package.json:/usr/src/package.json'
    ports:
      - '9000:9000' # expose ports - HOST:CONTAINER

  web-service:
    container_name: web-service
    build:
      context: ./services/web
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './services/web:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000' # expose ports - HOST:CONTAINER
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    depends_on:
      - user-service
```

***My user/ Dockerfile***

```
FROM node:latest

# set working directory
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
ADD package.json /usr/src/package.json
RUN npm install

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

***My web/ Dockerfile***

```
FROM node:latest

# set working directory
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@1.1.4
RUN npm install gulp -g

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you please post the contents of your current `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it. The issue was that my local node_modules were being copied to the host container. Hence in the sqlite3 lib/binding, node-v57-darwin-x64 was there instead of what is expected - node-v57-linux-x64. Hence the mess.

I updated the Dockerfiles and docker-compose.yml as follows:

***My docker-compose.yml***

```
services:
  user-service:
    container_name: user-service
    build: 
      context: ./services/user/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './services/user:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/node_modules'
    ports:
      - '9000:9000' # expose ports - HOST:CONTAINER

  web-service:
    container_name: web-service
    build:
      context: ./services/web/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - './services/web:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000' # expose ports - HOST:CONTAINER
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    depends_on:
      - user-service
```

My user/ Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest

# set working directory
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
ADD package.json /usr/src/package.json
RUN npm install

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Helpful posts
[Getting npm packages to be installed with docker-compose](http://dchua.com/2016/02/07/getting-npm-packages-to-be-installed-with-docker-compose/)